# How to use expr inside if statement?

Tags: if-statement, tcl, expr

I have not managed to understand how to embed expr in other constructs.
I can easily type

```
set i {1 2 3}
expr {[llength $i]} #result is 3
```

However after long research I have not managed to find a way to put that inside if

```
if {"magic tcl code with expr and llength==3 required here"} {
   puts "length is 3"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `if` is an expression, just as the argument to `expr` is an expression.

```
if {[llength $i] == 3} {
    puts "length is 3"
}
```

You can indeed put `expr` inside an expression using `[`brackets`]`, just as with any command, but there's usually no reason to do so; it just makes everything more verbose.

```
if {[ expr {[llength $i]} ] == 3} {
    puts "length is 3"
}
```

The exception to the above rule comes when you've got an expression that's somehow dynamic; that's when putting an `expr` inside an expression makes sense as it allows the outer parts to be bytecode-compiled efficiently.

```
# Trivial example to demonstrate
set myexpression {[llength $i]}

if {[expr $myexpression] == 3} {
    puts "evaluated $myexpression to get three"
}
```

That's pretty rare.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` command has a built-in expr. Specifically both `if` and `expr` expects and expression as the first argument:

```
if expression ...
expr expression
```

Therefore, if you want to execute `expr {[llength $i]}` then just do:

```
if {[llength $i]} {

}
```

But to tell you the truth, I don't believe you want to execute

```
expr {[llength $i]}
```

I think what you want is to check if the length is 3, therefore what you really want is

```
expr {[llength $i] == 3}
```

If that is the case, then the `if` version would be:

```
if {[llength $i] == 3} {
    puts "llength is 3"
}
```